# Three.js not rendering elements

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I am using modular Three.js with typescript. It creates the scene but it's not rendering any elements on the canvas.Here is my code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three/build/three.module'

class App {
    private scene = new THREE.Scene();
    private camera;
    private renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    private container = document.getElementById('widget');

    constructor() {
        this._init();
        let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: true });
        let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        this.scene.add(cube);

    }

    _init() {
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight, 1, 1000);
        this.camera.position.z = 5;
        this.scene.add(this.camera)
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    }
}

new App()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not rendering anything because you're not telling it to.

If you take a look at the "getting started" doc https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene, you should take notice that you're only doing the "creating the scene" part.

What you also need to do is the "Rendering the scene" part of that tutorial.

Somewhere, something needs to call `yourAppInstance.renderer.render()` method. You can either store your App instance in a variable

```
var myApp = new App()

myApp.renderer.render(myApp.camera, myApp.scene)
```

^ not sure how typescript works, you probably cant access these though.

You can also do it in your constructor

```
constructor() {
    this._init();
    let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: true });
    let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(cube);
    this.renderer.render(this.camera,this.scene) // <-- add this

}
```